# Multiple view with swipe and transition IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need your advice. 
I want to make an application like working [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezDnc.png) iPod music screen. I have lots of cards and when user choose one of them, it will turn. I couldn't find any tutorial or example about this, can you help me ? what should i do ?

I tried transitions, and swipe, but I couldn't do what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great library. Very stable and easy to use.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CococaPods](http://cocoapods.org) to install [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) library which can lead you how to use this kind of swipe between screens.

Comment: I make some search about community wiki again since you asked me that and there was something which i misunderstood. Sorry about that I'm gonna pay attention next time.

Comment: I don't know much about community wiki posts, my assumption is they are credible and not to be changed.